# Extract file name from Java URL (file: and http/https protocol)?

Tags: java, parsing, url, uri

I have various urls like this:

```
String a = "file:./bla/file.txt"; // Valid, see See [RFC 3986][1], path - rootless definition
String b = "file:.file.txt";      // Valid, see See [RFC 3986][1], path - rootless definition
String c = "file:./file.txt";     // Valid, see See [RFC 3986][1], path - rootless definition
String d = "file:///file.txt";
String e = "file:///folder/file.txt";
String f = "http://example.com/file.txt";
String g = "https://example.com/file.txt";
```

These are all valid URLS, and I can convert them to a URL in java without errors:

```
URL url = new URL(...);
```

I want to extract the filename from each of the examples above, so I'm left with just:

```
file.txt
```

I have tried the following, but this doesn't work for example `b` above (which is a valid URL):

```
b.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // Returns file:.file.txt
```

I can prob write some custom code to check for slashes, just wondering if there a better more robust way to do it?

Comment: You can use Path.of(urlstring).getFileName();

Comment: @MirekPluta Thanks, but that doesn't work for example b

Comment: Even URI class fails to parse it. It cannot be proper URI, otherwise you found bug in JDK

Comment: Wouldn't example b represent a hidden file in the current directory? ie `./.file.txt`   I wouldn't expect the file name to be `file.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class properly parses the parts of a URI.  For most URLs, you want the [path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#getPath()) of the URI.  In the case of a URI with no slashes, there won’t be any parsing of the parts, so you’ll have to rely on the entire [scheme-specific part](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#getSchemeSpecificPart()):

```
URI uri = new URI(b);
String path = uri.getPath();
if (path == null) {
    path = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
}
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

The above should work for all of your URLs.